# Disable - kendo column header selection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Setting kendo grid

```
    selectable: "row",
    navigatable: true,
```

allows to select column header cells and toggle their sort state from keyboard. 
**How to completely disable ability to select column header cell using keyboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible out of the box.  However you can check the following answer in Kendo UI forums for possible custom solution:

- [Grid: skip fields during navigation](http://www.telerik.com/forums/skip-read-only-fields-when-using-keyboard-navigation-on-navigatable-grid-in-batch-edit-mode)